# Why is my WiFi connection dropping out?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I believe this is quite unique.

### My Specs

Acer Travelmate P253e Laptop
8Gb Ram
1Tb HDD
Intel Celeron 1000 processor @ 1.7ghz
Windows 8.1
Broadcom Wireless Adapter

### The issue

My WiFi keeps dropping out randomly. I would guess 100 times a day, but I've tried everything I can see on the net.

The issue is somewhat more unique in that my father is able to connect and stay connected without issue and his laptop is next to mine (18 inches away), and I can also connect and stay connected via my smartphone (as can he) and the TV can also connect when necessary for Catch Up.

So with all that in mind, I am leaning towards an issue with my laptop.
I've been to the Acer website, downloaded the driver, installed and rebooted. However, there was no change. I've changed the antivirus as apparently that could be a cause. Again, there was no change.

I've reset the winsock from the CMD (run as Admin). There was no change. I've unchecked the power settings box as recommended. There was no change. I am running out of options, to be honest.

One thing I did think of was the wifi properties.

There are two protocols, IPv4 and IPv6: they are both "checked" and both set to automatic.  Now this is a new area to me so please be gentle ;-)
Do they both need to be "checked"? If not, which one should I have "checked"?
That being said, should they be set to automatic or should I set them manually by inserting the relevant data? In which case, where do I find the data to input?

One more thing, as I said previously, I downloaded the updated driver file from Acer for the WiFi adapter but I'm a bit confused on which .exe file to use: there is more than one setup.exe file and also a 64 folder (which I presume is for 64bit, which my machine is). Given this, could it be that I am not installing all the items needed for my adapter to function correctly?

Here are the screen shots of the main folder contents and the sub contents of the 64 folder. I am currently just double clicking the main setup.exe file near the bottom of the list. Maybe someone can shed some light on the other exe files and tell me whether I need them?

[image: File list]

[image: File list]

I am not completely clueless and am able to follow instructions to troubleshoot, so would be so grateful for any help before I launch this out of the window and spend another £400 I don't have on a new laptop.

Comment: Could you look in even viewer and see where it's dropping and if there are any error codes?

Comment: if you don't find anything in the event viewer (as @NetworkKingPin suggested) check if the device has power saving enabled and disable it. you could also try to boot a live linux distro and see if it will work, if it will behave in the same way it could be a hardware fault.

Comment: Try a live Linux distribution via USB... If it works fine, it's a software issue with Windows, if it exhibits similar behavior it is either defective hardware or an incompatibility issue (rare but they happen).

Answer (score 0):

For the driver installation, you should be able to install it using the `setup.exe` file in the top-level directory; it may check to see whether the 64-bit version can be installed on your system. If it doesn't check and installed the 32-bit version, that 32-bit version should still work on your system even though your system is capable of running 64-bit software.

What is the Wi-fi signal strength reported by your laptop?  You can check it by [obtaining a command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php) then typing the command `netsh wlan show interfaces` ([example](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2015/11/13)). You will see the signal strength on the "Signal" line. Even though both of you may be using the same wireless router or wireless access point, you may have different wireless adapters in your system and his may be better able to cope with a weak signal.

Is the [SSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Service_set_identification_.28SSID.29) listed the same on your system and your father's system, i.e., are you both using the same wireless network? Though likely you are, I would verify that, since there may be multiple wireless networks accessible from your location. You will see an SSID line in the output from the above command.

Is the "radio type" value listed the same on your laptop and your father's laptop? The router or access point may support both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz wireless radio frequency bands and his laptop may be using the 5 GHz band while yours is using the 2.4 GHz band. If you know the router supports the 5 Ghz band, but your system is using the 2.4 GHz band, try the 5 GHz band, if your laptop's wireless network adapter supports it. You can check whether it does by issuing the command `netsh wlan show drivers` at a command prompt; if you see "802.11a" in the "Radio types supported" line it supports the 5 GHz band - see [Determining if a Windows system supports the 5 GHz Wifi band](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/network/5GHz-supported.php) for an example and further information.

To determine if the problem may be within the operating system rather than with the hardware you could use a Linux [Live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) as Zina suggested. E.g. [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) is a popular distribution of Linux. If you can boot your laptop from an alternative operating system and don't have the network dropout problem, then the problem is likely an issue within Windows rather than with the wireless network adapter. You didn't list the model of your [Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/) wireless adapter, but if there is no diagnostic program installed for the adapter when you install an updated driver, it is possible you could find a diagnostic program at [Broadcom's website](http://www.broadcom.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with poor connectivity in my living room, with my router located in the basement. This was only on one laptop: that laptop (Dell) would get no connection at all in the library two floors from the basement.

I found two cures:

1. I bought an external USB antenna: Hawking technology HWUN4. This solved my problem in the living area (one floor above the basement where my ADSL router/wireless modem is located).
2. I placed an additional wireless router in the library (second floor above the basement) and have it named differently with different a wireless access key than the main modem router. This solution does require you to log in to the second wireless network when on the second floor. I have a CAT 5 wired network throughout the house which made adding the additional router easy.

You may also try moving your wireless router or adding a booster to it.

Comment: It would have been less expensive and less trouble to add a WAP instead of a second router in the library. You paid for the router, firewall, DHCP, etc. just to get the WAP part of your router. It is easy to just add a WAP to an existing network.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion was that my laptop was nearer to the router (by 18 inches) than my father's even though we both always had maximum bars, so distance wasn't an issue. Since this morning I have discovered what *was* the issue so I'm sharing it with everyone as this was not something I had either considered nor was it mentioned on any discussion board in the last few days as a potential solution.

Downloads:  When just surfing this morning for a few hours I couldn't believe everything was running fine, so I caught up with a few things I had to do and come lunchtime I realised, damn, need to download my TV stuff - launched µTorrent and boing - the wifi dropped!

This, of course, got me thinking (bearing in mind that I've always used µTorrent and always used this version (the old and most stable one) and *never* had an issue).

So, I closed µTorrent, worked for another hour online with the wifi remaining stable, launched µTorrent and activated a download: boing, the net crashed again!

So, I went search again for wifi crashing when downloading, the the search results for this query were a different ball game: to cut a long story short, I changed the following settings and everything is now fine and dandy!

Why it should all of a sudden make a difference I don't know, but apparently it's since most people have moved to fibre, but anyhow all is fine, no more issues, and all is stable, so thanks so much to all the replies - even though having read a couple of them I wouldn't even know what an event viewer was even if it dropped it's pants in front of me!

Here is the screenshot of the two things I changed so as hopefully it'll help someone else or at the very least is something to try.

[image: Screenshot of settings window]

The two highlighted figures are what I've changed. They *were* by default set at: 100 (global max connections) and 50 (max connected peers per torrent). 
Everything still downloads as fast, etc., but if you find it slows yours down at all just increase the values slowly: it's trial and error, I guess, but it'll not do you any harm to try it for yourself and see what suits.